# Get the equation of a circle when given 30 points

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

> A similar question has been asked before on this site but that was of
>   getting equation of circle using 3 points.

I want my center to be more accurate
So my question is how can i get the center of the circle using 30 coordinates on its circumference. Please help me to know how can i get it.

Comment: You should explain more about why a "more accurate" center is important.  In particular do you know something about errors in the points, how these errors are distributed?  If every point were perfectly accurate, then any three would give exactly the same center, but when errors appear a number of schemes (best least squares, best min-max, etc.) could be proposed.  The choice of scheme likely depends on your purpose and the distribution of errors.

Comment: You only need 3 points. Ditch 27 of them unless the points aren't exactly on the circumference in which case you may require a method of approximation.

Comment: A circle is uniquely determined by three points. Given 30 points you can have $\binom{30}{3}$ different circles. You really need to say something about why you expect them to be on the same circle, and why you don't just use three of them.

Comment: @Henrik Maybe what the OP looking for is:- among these $\binom{30}{3}$ circles, which one best-fits these 30 points.

Comment: There are a number of questions we could invent and speculate the OP is actually asking -- it would be better to have the OP to fill in the missing context. Based on one of the comments, it sounds like the OP actually has a very specific problem, and could get a very specific answer if the OP actually filled in the details of the question!

Comment: @Hudixit Are the points on the *same* circle? If on same circle, whether there are 3 points or 3 million points the center and radius will be same.We can keep any three points and discard the remaining. If the points are around a circle then $ x^2+y^2+ 2fx + 2gy+c $ using 3 constants can be solved for using least squares.

Comment: @Narasimham i Just realized that they are not on the same circle. Actually i am processing an image.... So i can't find them in the proper circle......

Comment: I'm curious about whether any of the offered methods leads readily to a standard deviation of the centre and/or radius.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A circle centered at $(h,k)$ of radius $r$ has equation $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2.$ So you can expand this equation and use your thirty points along with least squares to do it.

Comment: I think it's easier to do this with $Dx+Ey+F=x^2+y^2$

Comment: @NobleMushtak Yes, that way one has only three undetermined coefficients and it may be easier to set up for least squares. Using the expanded form I suggested there are still three unknown coefficents but after multiplying out a term $h^2+k^2-r^2$ remains, which (to me) is not so direct.

Comment: Least-squares may not be ideal because there is no 1:1 function y = f(x).  There are published algorithms for fitting a conic section.  Personally I like the RANSAC-based ellipse fits (which covers a circle, of course).  Or you could convert to $ r-\theta$ space.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is much more complex since it depends how you express the objective function (in other words, what kind of distances to the circle you want to consider).

Probably the simplest (**method 1**) would be what  Noble Mushtak commented that is to say to find the best $D,E,F$ parameters in the model $$Dx_i+Ey_i+F=x_i^2+y_i^2$$ Using matrices, the solution is almost immediate.

Another simple and explicit method I  remember is given [here](http://www.dtcenter.org/met/users/docs/write_ups/circle_fit.pdf).

More rigorous (**method 2**) will be to minimize $$F(a,b,r)=\sum_{i=1}^n \left( (x_i-a)^2+(y_i-b)^2-r^2\right)^2$$ The partial derivatives are simple to write but they lead to a nonlinear system of equations. However, you could use the first method to get good estimates of the solution and start a Newton-Raphson procedure to polish the solution.

Still more rigorous (**method 3**) would be to consider $$d_i=\sqrt{(x_i-a)^2 + (y_i-b)^2} - r$$ which represents the distance from the perimeter to  point $(x_i,y_i)$ and to minimize $$G(a,b,r)=\sum_{i=1}^n d_i^2$$ Same problem as before and same solution.

Since the first method gives reasonable estimates, I suppose that the final solution could be obtained using Excel solver as a black box tool.

You could also use the method published [here](https://fr.scribd.com/document/14819165/Regressions-coniques-quadriques-circulaire-spherique) by Jean Jacquelin (he is a MSE user). The book is in French but you will not have any problem. Have a look at pages $12-13$. It is a very simple method and example is given.

**Edit**

For illustration purposes, I used the following data points
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2.5 & 6.5 \\
 2.0 & 8.5 \\
 4.0 & 11.5 \\
 7.5 & 11.0 \\
 9.0 & 9.0 \\
 8.0 & 6.5
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using  **method 1**, we find $D=10.81773$, $E=16.84893$, $F=-88.579820$ which correspond to $a=5.40887$, $b=8.42447$, $r=3.41287$.

Using  **method 2**, we get the same results (this is normal).

Using  **method 3**, we obtain  $a=5.39989$, $b=8.42763$, $r=3.41031$.

Answer (score 5):

A circle is not made more accurate by adding more points.  3 non-colinear points fully defines the equation for a circle.  Your remaining 27 points are either perfectly on this circle, adding nothing, or they are not perfectly on the circle, in which case there is no equation for a circle through all 30 points.

It strikes me that you are not looking for the equation for a circle that goes through those 30 points, but the best fit for a circle which *almost* goes through each point.  This is a fitting process, not a simple analytic geometry problem.

For a best fit, you have to define what "best fit" means to you.  Often it means minimizing the sum of the squares of the errors.  Claude Leibovici's answer does a good job of going down that path.

Answer (score 3):

If all of the points lie on a common circle, then take the first three points and then find the circle that intersects those three points. Since all of the points lie on the same circle, all of the points must lie on the same circle as the first three points, so the circle of the first three points is the same as the circle of the whole set.

Comment: I already did that..... but as i was processing an image i found that the image was somewhat skewed. So that was giving some error in finding the center. By the way thanks

Comment: @Hudixt The simplest and messiest way then is to just take random sets of 3 points and average the centers of the circle based on those sets of points.

Comment: Let's [move this discussion to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42247/room-for-nobel-and-bjb568).

Answer (score 1):

Pixels in an image are never "accurate" so 3 are insufficient. The circle Hough Transform (CHT) is used for detecting circular objects (and other shapes). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Hough_Transform
It is computationally complex (slow!) and works by transforming the image into 3d "parameter space" where the axes are the possible circle centres (a, b) and the circle radii R. Other useful links are a 2005 lecture: https://www.cis.rit.edu/class/simg782/lectures/lecture_10/lec782_05_10.pdf
and the openCV documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Pick up arbitrary two point, write down the equation of perpendicular line which passes through the midpoint of these two point. Denote the equation for the line as $E1$.

Pick up different arbitrary two point, write down the equation of perpendicular line which passes through the midpoint of these two point. Denote the equation for the line as $E2$.

Set $E1$ and $E2$ into a system of equation, solve it (i.e. find the intersection point of line $E1$ and line $E2$). The solution with respect to $x$ and $y$ is the coordinate of center of the circle.

EDIT: notice that if $E1$ and $E2$ parallel, then $E1$ and $E2$ has numerous solutions.

When use other two point, check whether line about these point is parallel to the one about first chosen points.

Comment: You should also guarantee that you don't end up with the same line when you choose the other two points. A simple trick would be choosing two points $A$ and $B$, take that line you mentioned, and then take another point $C\neq A,B$ and take the line perpendicular to $AC$ and passing through their midpoints. It also explains why three non-linear points give a unique circle.

Comment: That's why the word "different" there. The problem of my solution is that the coefficient matrix of $E1$ and $E2$ doesn't have full rank.

Comment: If the 30 points are symmetric on the circle, for example, the bisector of points 0 and 1 is also the bisector of points 15 and 16. I think that's what @Levent meant by “guarantee that you don't end up with the same line”.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?  For each pair of points $P_i, P_j$ construct the bisector line $L_{ij}$; the point that minimizes the sum of squared distances from $L_{ij}$ is a candidate centre for the circle.  The setup is quadratic in number of points (unless you know the sequence of the points along the circumference, in which case it's reasonable to use only N lines), but the solution is trivial, equivalent to finding the apex of an elliptic paraboloid.

I have used the method given here: http://www.dtcenter.org/met/users/docs/write_ups/circle_fit.pdf

I have not got around to reading this: http://www.spaceroots.org/documents/circle/circle-fitting.pdf

**Afterthought:** If the input is noisy or quantized, it's likely best *not* to use (only) bisectors of adjacent pairs; better to pair each point with the one most distant.